# Auto update backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, render

I'm having a problem re rendering a simple collection in backbone, the render event is never fired from the listeners... I'm not sure of where is the mistake, could please someone help me?

File with models:

```
window.MetricDevice = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      ip: null,
      framesReceived: null,
      framesOutOfOrder: null,
      framesLost: null
 }
});

window.MetricDevicesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MetricDevice,
  value: null,
  url: function(){
      return hackBase + "/wm/iptv/metric/devices/json";  
  },
  initialize:function () { 
      this.fetch({ reset: true });
      console.log("data fetched");
  },      
});
```

Render page:

```
window.MetricItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click input[type=button]" : "removeDevice",
    },
    initialize:function(){
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('metric-devices-item'));
        this.render();
},
removeDevice:function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:hackBase +  '/wm/iptv/metric/disable/' + this.model.get("ip") + '/0/json',
        dataType:"json",
        success:function (data) {
            if ( data.return == 1 ){
                alert(data.error);  
            }else{
                alert("Metric disabled in " + this.model.get("ip"));
            }
        },
    });
},
render:function(){      
    var ip = this.model.get("ip");
    console.log("rendering item in view " + ip);

},

});

window.MetricView = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
    "click input[type=button]" : "add",
    "click input[type=img]" : "updateAll",
},
clicked:function(e){

},
updateAll:function(e){
    this.render();
},
initialize:function () {
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('metric-devices-list'));
    this.model.bind("change", function(){
        console.log("metricView data change detected");
        this.render();
    });
    this.model.bind("reset", this.render());
},
add:function(e){
    if($(e.currentTarget).attr("name") == "add" ){
        var ip = document.getElementById('vaddress').value;
        var threshold = document.getElementById('vthreshold').value;
        $.ajax({
            url:hackBase +  '/wm/iptv/metric/enable/' + ip + '/' + threshold + '/json',
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (data) {
                if ( data.return == 1 ){
                    alert(data.error);  
                }else{
                    alert("Metric enabled in device");
                }
            },
        });
    }else if($(e.currentTarget).attr("name") == "cancel"){          
        document.getElementById('vaddress').value = "";
        document.getElementById('vthreshold').value = "";
    }
},    
render:function (eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    var list = $(this.el).find('#tableData');
    console.log("On render!");
    var subviews = [];
    console.log("looping on models");
    _.each(this.model.models, function (sw) {
       console.log("model loop " + sw.get("ip"));
       var m = new MetricItemView({model:sw, tagName: 'tbody', el: $(this.el).find('#tableData')});
       list.append(m.template(sw.toJSON()));
    }, this);

    return this;
},

});
```

The problem is that the render method in MetricView is called just when the page is loaded for the first time, and after this I've the impression that the JSON stay cached, and the content just change if I close the browser clean the cache and run again...

The console output is:

```
On render! metricView.js:86
looping on models metricView.js:88
model loop 10.0.0.1 metricView.js:92
rendering item in view 10.0.0.1 metricView.js:26
```

And I'm instantiating MetricView like this

```
var metricdevices = new MetricDevicesCollection();
$('#content').html(new MetricView({model:metricdevices}).render().el);
```

Am i forgetting something?

Comment: Do you have some error in your console?

Comment: No just the debugging messages:


`code`
    On render! (metricView.js:86)

    looping on (models metricView.js:88)

    d {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, _callbacks: Object…}    (metricView.js:89)

    model loop 10.0.0.1 metricView.js:92

    rendering item in view 10.0.0.1

`code`

Comment: How are you instantiating `MetricView`? (Tip: Edit the qestion instead of post code or console output as a comment)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanNaguin, I updated the question with the console and the class initialization.

Comment: Are you chaging the content of `metricdevices` in some place? Because it seems you are only calling `fetch` in the `initialize` function...

Comment: No, I'm not sure of how backbone works, it don't look for the content of the JSON page by itself? If not, how could I force it to do it from time to time? Or would make a call to fetch() from time to time be enough? (sorry, I'm kind of a noob in webdev)

Comment: Ohh right... You are fetching the content when the collection is instantiate, but then you have to "refresh" the collection via a button or using a `setInterval`

Comment: @JonathanNaguin there's only a small problem, using set interval like `code`setInterval(this.model.refresh,1500);`code` on the view has no effect and if I try this.model.fetch I get a error saying that the url was not been provided... how would you implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are not using Backbone models and collection at their full potential. When you are calling manual `$.ajax(...)`, no Backbone event will fire. Here are a couple suggestions that would make your code integrate with Backbone.

First, you should instantiate your view with the proper reserved keyword: `collection`

```
var metricdevices = new MetricDevicesCollection();
$('#content').html(new MetricView({ collection : metricdevices }).render().el);
```

Backbone events in collection are intended to work with precise REST API practices. A `Model` that belongs to a `Collection` will inherit it's `url` parameter. It expects your REST API to map to the following scheme:

```
model.save()   --> model.id is present ? PUT collection.url/model.id : POST collection.url
model.delete() --> DELETE collection.url/model.id
model.fetch()  --> GET collection.url/model.id
```

The idea is that you can manipulate models individually and use collection to fetch all the relevant models when needed. Your API does not seem to be adapted for that kind of workflow.
A *monky patch* that would keep your data updated is to trigger a `fetch` of the collection when an operation succeeds.

```
var collection = this.collection;
$.ajax({
  //...
  success: {
    collection.fetch();
  }
}
```

Since you are already listening to the Backbone events, it will trigger the `reset` event and render the view. Note that this is **not** a good way of doing things. What you should do is refactor your server access points to conform to standard good REST practice if you have access to it. If you don't, use proper Object Oriented patterns and implement model behavior in the model. For example:

```
window.MetricDevice = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        ip: null,
        framesReceived: null,
        framesOutOfOrder: null,
        framesLost: null
    },
    enable : function() {
        var device = this,
            ip = this.ip,
            treshold = this.treshold;
        $.ajax({
            url:hackBase +  '/wm/iptv/metric/enable/' + ip + '/' + threshold + '/json',
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (data) {
                if ( data.return == 1 ){
                    alert(data.error);  
                } else {
                    device.trigger('change');                    
                    alert("Metric enabled in device");
                }
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

And then you can properly call the object from a view:

```
var ip = document.getElementById('vaddress').value;
var threshold = document.getElementById('vthreshold').value;
var metricDevice = new MetricDevice({ ip : ip, treshold : treshold });
this.collection.add(metricDevice.enable());
```

Comment: But I need to update the data on the view independently of user input, my website is using data on internet to change the rest api page values. Will it see those changes even without user input?